# Full width drop up sub-navigation Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a footer menu with a drop up and full width sub-navigation for mobile devices with Bootstrap 3. I already create the drop up with some css and made the sub-navigation align to the left (I don't know if this is the best way but it works) I've been trying a lot of ways and checking a lot of examples, but I can't figure out how to made the sub navigation cover the full width of the screen.
Here is my example working in this Bootply http://www.bootply.com/7wy0Oten9m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that whatever you set all the col-xs-2 classes define the width of your drop-up. The solution here is to say goodbye to Bootstrap for a little bit.

The idea:

1. Footer --> col-xs-12 (full width)
2. Put all 5 pieces of menu into it (all have the class "button-footer-mobile") and set their width to 16.66667% (which was
   the 2-col width)
3. Give the middle-menu another class and set it to 33.33333% (the 4-col width) /the class is middlemenu in my example/
4. Float the "button-footer-mobile" class to the left and set it's margin to 0.

This way you have the same layout but the drop-ups can now have a 100% width.

**You can see a working bootply here**: http://www.bootply.com/lyLNGBDZ68#

I hope it helped you and my answer is clear and understandable,

Andrew

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrew! The answer was really clear and easy to apply.